# Why is the Facet_Grid Output Different from Its Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2, facet-grid

I have these time series data which I plotted as follows

```
## simulate ARIMA(1, 0, 0)
set.seed(289805)
x1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(671086)
x2 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(799837)
x3 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(289805)
x4 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(671086)
x5 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(799837)
x6 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(289805)
x7 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(671086)
x8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(799837)
x9 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(289805)
x10 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(671086)
x11 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(799837)
x12 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
xx <- 1:10


# ggplot for x1
plot1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x1, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x2
plot2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x2, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x3
plot3 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x3, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x4
plot4 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x4, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x5
plot5 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x5, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x6
plot6 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x6, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x7
plot7 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x7, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x8
plot8 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x8, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x9
plot9 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x9, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x10
plot10 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x10, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x11
plot11 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x11, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))


# ggplot for x12
plot12 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x12, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))


# plot in a 3 by 5 grid by using plot_layout
plot1 + plot2 + plot3 + plot4 + plot5 + plot6 + plot7 + plot8 + plot9 + plot10 + plot11 + plot12 + patchwork::plot_layout(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

[image: Grid Arranged Plot]

I now want to give it a face-lift with `facet_grid` which I tried as follows

```
df <- data.frame(xx, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12)
reshapp <- reshape2::melt(df, id = "xx")

NEWDAT <- data.frame(y = reshapp$value, x = reshapp$xx, sd = rep(c(1,3,5,10), each = 3), phi = rep(c(.8, .9, .95), 4))

ggplot(NEWDAT, aes(x = x, y = y)) +  geom_line() +  geom_point() + facet_grid(sd ~ phi,  scales = "free_y") +
```

theme_bw() + ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

[image: Facet_Grid Plot]

**WHAT I WANT**

How do I make the `Facet_Grid Plot` to be what `Grid_Arranged Plot` is?

**POINTER**

One can see that the `lowest` data point in the first series is `-0.2505125` while the `highest` is `4.6956397`. In the `Facet-Grid Plot` the `lowest is -20+` and the `highest is 30+`.

Comment: Interesting - Apparently you ran into the same trap a month ago, as I did yesterday :) See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69863292/7941188 - the problem was the wrong repetition in the data frame. I think you can delete that question now?

Comment: I meant this bountied question here, of course. I hope I could help you

Comment: Questions with open bounties cannot be deleted

Comment: I will wait till it expires, then I will delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I read the comments, I can see that you are going to delete this question. However, I would like to ask you to take a moment to look at my solution. I think it is much simpler and more transparent.

We will start with a simple `tibble` in which the parameters of your calculations will be.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  seed = rep(c(289805, 671086, 799837), 4),
  sd = rep(c(1, 3, 5, 10), each=3),
  ar = rep(c(.8, .9, .95), 4)
)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
     seed    sd    ar
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 289805     1  0.8 
 2 671086     1  0.9 
 3 799837     1  0.95
 4 289805     3  0.8 
 5 671086     3  0.9 
 6 799837     3  0.95
 7 289805     5  0.8 
 8 671086     5  0.9 
 9 799837     5  0.95
10 289805    10  0.8 
11 671086    10  0.9 
12 799837    10  0.95
```

Now we are preparing one simple `farima` function.

```
farima = function(seed, n, ar, order, sd){ 
  set.seed(seed)
  model = arima.sim(n=n, model=list(ar = ar, order = order), sd = sd)
  tibble(
    name = paste("sd -", sd, "ar -", ar),
    x = model %>% as.numeric(), 
    lb = 1:length(x)
    )
}
```

All you have to do afterwards is **one simple mutation!**

```
df %>% nest_by(seed, ar, sd) %>% 
  mutate(data = list(farima(seed, 10, ar, c(1, 0, 0), sd))) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lb, x))+
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF")+
  geom_point(color = "#101820FF")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))+
  facet_wrap(.~name, ncol = 3, scales = "free")
```

[image]

But you can also do it a bit differently.

```
df %>% nest_by(seed, ar, sd) %>% 
  mutate(data = list(farima(seed, 10, ar, c(1, 0, 0), sd))) %>% 
  unnest(data) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lb, x))+
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF")+
  geom_point(color = "#101820FF")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))+
  facet_grid(vars(sd), vars(ar), scales = "free")
```

[image]

I hope you like my solution and instead of deleting this question you will mark it as useful.

### Small update for @Daniel James

You have to understand well what happens when you use the `nest_by` function. I'll show you step by step.

```
df %>% nest_by(seed, ar, sd) %>% #Step 1
  mutate(data = list(farima(seed, 10, ar, c(1, 0, 0), sd))) %>% #Step 2
  unnest(data) %>% #Step 3
  ggplot(aes(lb, x))+ #Step 4
  geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF")+
  geom_point(color = "#101820FF")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))+
  facet_wrap(.~name, ncol = 3, scales = "free")
```

After the first step, you get a shattered `tibble`, however, not by variables but **by rows**. The `date` variable appears here, which in this case is basically empty (it contains the zero value).

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Rowwise:  seed, ar, sd
     seed    ar    sd               data
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list<tibble[,0]>>
 1 289805  0.8      1            [1 x 0]
 2 289805  0.8      3            [1 x 0]
 3 289805  0.8      5            [1 x 0]
 4 289805  0.8     10            [1 x 0]
 5 671086  0.9      1            [1 x 0]
 6 671086  0.9      3            [1 x 0]
 7 671086  0.9      5            [1 x 0]
 8 671086  0.9     10            [1 x 0]
 9 799837  0.95     1            [1 x 0]
10 799837  0.95     3            [1 x 0]
11 799837  0.95     5            [1 x 0]
12 799837  0.95    10            [1 x 0]
```

If you do the mutation now, it will apply to the values in each row.

So let's see what we have after step two.

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Rowwise:  seed, ar, sd
     seed    ar    sd data             
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>           
 1 289805  0.8      1 <tibble [10 x 3]>
 2 289805  0.8      3 <tibble [10 x 3]>
 3 289805  0.8      5 <tibble [10 x 3]>
 4 289805  0.8     10 <tibble [10 x 3]>
 5 671086  0.9      1 <tibble [10 x 3]>
 6 671086  0.9      3 <tibble [10 x 3]>
 7 671086  0.9      5 <tibble [10 x 3]>
 8 671086  0.9     10 <tibble [10 x 3]>
 9 799837  0.95     1 <tibble [10 x 3]>
10 799837  0.95     3 <tibble [10 x 3]>
11 799837  0.95     5 <tibble [10 x 3]>
12 799837  0.95    10 <tibble [10 x 3]>
```

Note that our `farima` function used in the `mutate` function for the arguments `seed`, `ar` and `sd` received single values on each row! Also pay attention to use the `list` function in which you will wrap our `farima` function.

Now all we have to do is solve our `data` variable. We'll do this in step 3.

```
# A tibble: 120 x 6
# Groups:   seed, ar, sd [12]
     seed    ar    sd name                 x    lb
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            <dbl> <int>
 1 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8 -0.251     1
 2 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  0.886     2
 3 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  0.198     3
 4 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  1.54      4
 5 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  4.70      5
 6 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  4.44      6
 7 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  3.02      7
 8 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  1.81      8
 9 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  1.17      9
10 289805   0.8     1 sd - 1 ar - 0.8  1.16     10
# ... with 110 more rows
```

Everything that happens in step 4 and beyond is just creating the appropriate charts.

Comment: I must agree that your answer suits my question properly.

Comment: I want to learn from your approach. I ran this: `farima = function(seed, n, ar, order, sd){ 
  set.seed(seed)
  model = arima.sim(n=n, model=list(ar = ar, order = order), sd = sd)
  tibble(
    name = paste("sd -", sd, "ar -", ar),
    x = model %>% as.numeric(), 
    lb = 1:length(x)
  )
}` and this `seed = rep(c(289805, 671086, 799837), 4);
sd = rep(c(1, 3, 5, 10), each=3);
ar = rep(c(.8, .9, .95), 4);
farima(seed, 10, ar, c(1, 1, 0), sd)` and got this error massage: `Error in arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ar = ar, order = order), sd = sd) : 
'ar' part of model is not stationary`

Comment: how can I make this expression above `stationary`? Or better asked as `what am I missing in the expression?`

Comment: Do this `farima(seed[1], 10, ar[1], c(1, 1, 0), sd[1])` then you will be fine.

Comment: I recommend that you familiarize yourself with [this vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Code

### Create data frame

```r
df <- data.frame(
    timestamp = rep(1:10, times = 12),
    value = c(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12),
    # via sprintf() to add a leading zero for easier ordering
    sim_id = paste0("x", sprintf("%02d", rep(1:12, each = 10)))
)
```

### Plot data

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = timestamp, y = value)) +
    geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") +
    geom_point(color = "#101820FF") +
    labs(x = "lb", y = "RMSE") +
    theme_bw() + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    # Facet wrap with set number of columns and free scales
    facet_wrap(. ~ sim_id, ncol = 3, scales = "free")
```

[image]

## Data

```r
library(ggplot2)

## simulate ARIMA(1, 0, 0)
set.seed(289805)
x1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(671086)
x2 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(799837)
x3 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(289805)
x4 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(671086)
x5 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(799837)
x6 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(289805)
x7 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(671086)
x8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(799837)
x9 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(289805)
x10 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(671086)
x11 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(799837)
x12 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
```