# How to Use Facet Grid For My Type of Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have this 12-time series generated data which I have plotted each as a time plot using `ggplot2`. I want to arrange the 12 of the plots into 1 single plot to make it a `3D` using `facet_grid` where the column name is `colname <- c("0.8", "0.9", "0.95")` and the row name is `rowname <- c("sd = 1", "sd = 3", "sd = 5", "sd = 10")` and the arrangement will be a `4 by 3` layout.

```
## simulate ARIMA(1, 0, 0)
set.seed(289805)
x1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(671086)
x2 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(799837)
x3 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
set.seed(289805)
x4 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(671086)
x5 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(799837)
x6 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 3)
set.seed(289805)
x7 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(671086)
x8 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(799837)
x9 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 5)
set.seed(289805)
x10 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(671086)
x11 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.9, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
set.seed(799837)
x12 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.95, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 10)
xx <- 1:10

# ggplot for x1
plot1 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x1, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x2
plot2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x2, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x3
plot3 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x3, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x4
plot4 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x4, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x5
plot5 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x5, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x6
plot6 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x6, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x7
plot7 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x7, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x8
plot8 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x8, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x9
plot9 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x9, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x10
plot10 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x10, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))

# ggplot for x11
plot11 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x11, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))


# ggplot for x12
plot12 <- ggplot2::ggplot(NULL, aes(y = x12, x = xx)) +  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "#F2AA4CFF") + ggplot2::geom_point(color = "#101820FF") + xlab('lb') + ylab('RMSE') +  ggplot2::theme_bw()+ ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.00))


# plot in a 3 by 5 grid by using plot_layout
plot1 + plot2 + plot3 + plot4 + plot5 + plot6 + plot7 + plot8 + plot9 + plot10 + plot11 + plot12 + patchwork::plot_layout(ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

[image: ggplot]

I want it to be like this

[image]
.

**EDIT**

May be there is need for its `data frame` version

```
df <- data.frame(xx, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12)
```

Comment: The first 3 series is simulated while `sd = 1` while the 4th to 6th is simulated with `sd = 3`, the 7th to 9th series is simulated with `sd = 5` and the 10th to 12th series is simulated with `sd = 10`.

Comment: Since I want 4 rows of 3 series, the first row is labelled `sd =1` the second row is labelled `sd = 3`, the third row is labelled `sd = 5` and the fourth row is labelled  `sd = 10`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the Facet\_Grid Output Different from Its Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69315757/why-is-the-facet-grid-output-different-from-its-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use ggplot, you will need data frames. One way to deal with your problem could be for example:

**edit** after you've specified that you struggle with the layout, here one way. As you're calculating the time series fairly manually, you will need to manually stipulate the sd/CI information by adding it to your data frame. Then you can use that information in the formula syntax within `facet_grid`

```r
## This requires an empty environment
## first make a list of all objects in the environment with the pattern x[number]
## mget retrieves all those objects
## the subsetting operator is to bring it into the right order
ls_ts <- mget(ls(pattern = "x[0-9]+"))[paste0("x", 1:length(ls(pattern = "x[0-9]+")))]

newdat <-
  data.frame(
    y = unlist(lapply(ls_ts, as.data.frame)),
    x = xx, sd = rep(rep(c(1, 3, 5, 10), each = 10), each = 3),
    CI = rep(rep(c(.8, .9, .95), each = 10), 4)
  )

ggplot(newdat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "lb", y = "RMSE") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_grid(sd ~ CI, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It is better at a `4 by 3` layout.

Comment: Please, what modification do my `data`  need that you never use it for your illustration?

Comment: I mean how do I manipulate my data so it can work for the plot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238954/discussion-between-daniel-james-and-tjebo).

Comment: Your generated data is never the same as your plot

Comment: my concern is that the plot I made with `patchwork` is different from yours

Comment: @DanielJames see update, the problem was the incorrect manual assignment. A very good case in point that you should avoid manual assignments like the pest - it's better to find a more programmatic way to create your time series.

Comment: Please point the manual assessment of a thing to me clearly let me learn. Please do show me a better way in the stance.

Comment: It will be better for me you explain to me how you created the variable ls_ts so I can flow along

Comment: see comments in the code

Comment: Basically, my data do come in `data frame` like this `df <- data.frame(xx, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12)` and for the `facet_grid()` function sake I reshaped the `data frame` like this `reshapp <- reshape2::melt(df, id = "xx")` I then form a new data data as `NEWDAT <- data.frame(y = reshapp$value, x = reshapp$xx, sd = rep(c(1,3,5,10), each = 3), phi = rep(c(.8, .9, .95), 4))` which you named `newdat`

Comment: yeah, but check how to correctly repeat sd and phi - see my code. Did the same mistake as you yesterday.

Comment: Please for my learning sake, dogmatically follow my steps stated in the just above comment and correct me on that.

Comment: Sorry, Daniel, I'll leave this to you - you should be able to find the solution based on the above, you're almost there. Compare how I used `rep` and how you used it.